# What test of significance is best suited to compare concentrations, with only one sample of each population?

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences, small-sample

I have two large reservoirs of water with unknown concentrations of bacteria. I have only one sample of each reservoir:

Sample of reservoir A:  volume of the sample $=V_1$, number of bacteria in the sample $=N_1$

Sample of reservoir B:  volume of the sample $=V_2$, number of bacteria in the sample $=N_2$

$N_1$ or $N_2$ are not necessarily large.

What test of significance should I use to estimate the probability that the two reservoirs have different concentrations of bacteria?

Comment: Do you know the standard error of the instrument/method?

Comment: No, I don't know it. The instrument can be taken to be ideal. The only source of variance would come from random sampling errors, but having only one sample of each population I do not see how to estimate it.

Comment: Researchers must have used this method in the past, no? There must be some idea of error around this instrument I would think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the hypotheses are $H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2$ vs $H_1:\mu_1\neq\mu_2$.

One approach might be to assume that the two counts are Poisson with exposure equal to the volume,

$N_1\sim\text{Pois}(V_1\cdot\mu_1)$

$N_2\sim\text{Pois}(V_2\cdot\mu_2)$

and to do a likelihood ratio test.

You could instead condition on the total and do a proportions test: Let $T=N_1+N_2$, then under $H_0$, $$N_1|T \sim \text{Bin}(T,\frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2})\,.$$

If the counts are expected to be not too small, then this can be done as a Z-test:

$$Z=\frac{
          N_1-T\frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2}
         }{
          \frac{\sqrt{TV_1V_2}}{V_1+V_2}
         }
     =
\frac{
          N_1(V_1+V_2)-TV_1
         }{
          \sqrt{TV_1V_2}
         }
$$

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful. I like the two approaches that you propose.